# Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2012, case

I have a date in my database which should not have included the year, so I need to construct the correct date by checking the date. (If the date is yet to come this year, I want to set 2017, if the date has passed, I want to set 2018)
(t.myDate is a nullable datetime)

```
SELECT
    NewDate = CASE
                 WHEN DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE()) < DATEPART(dayofyear, t.myDate)
                    THEN DATEFROMPARTS('2017', DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate), DATEPART(DAY, t.myDate))
                    ELSE DATEFROMPARTS('2018', DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate), DATEPART(DAY,t.myDate))
              END
FROM
    MyTable t
```

However, in some cases I get the following error message:

> Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I know some rows are NULL. So I have tried to get around the problem by using the CASE expression to simply use today's date in the cases where the problem is:

```
SELECT 
    NewDate = CASE
                 WHEN t.myDate is null
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate) < 1
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate) > 12
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN DATEPART(DAY,t.myDate) < 1
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN DATEPART(DAY,t.myDate) > 31
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN ISDATE(t.myDate) = 0
                    THEN GETDATE()
                 WHEN DATEPART(dayofyear, GETDATE()) < DATEPART(dayofyear, t.myDate)
                    THEN DATEFROMPARTS('2017', DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate), DATEPART(DAY, t.myDate))
                ELSE DATEFROMPARTS('2018', DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate), DATEPART(DAY,t.myDate))
             END
FROM
    MyTable t
```

But I still get the same error. Either I'm testing for the wrong data quality issues, or the CASE expression is not working as I expect it to.

Also: It does not help to use a where clause for NULL rows:

```
WHERE t.myDate IS NOT NULL
```

How can I find the data quality issue, and how can I get around it?

(I'm using SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from checking for NULL you may also have a problem with 29th of February. If you for example have date `2016-02-29` and you are trying to construct date `2017-02-29` you will get above error since this is not a valid date.

In general you could use cursor to loop over records and execute your logic inside `TRY/CATCH`. On exception you could print offending data and check what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check for that

Comment: Yes, it worked! Adding the following as the first CASE clause fixed it:
WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate) = 2 AND DATEPART(DAY,t.myDate) = 29)
  THEN DATEFROMPARTS('2018', DATEPART(MONTH,t.myDate), DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, t.myDate)))